# Null pointer issue in POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have another issue with my code. I have a error 
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

which I understand is a initialization matter. However I dont know how to initialize the HSSFRow object 'row'(netbean says 'row' must be initialized).

the Error line is the 10th line just before the ' for ' loop . when I run the code with an integer value like 4 for the variable ' cols', everything is fine.

here the summary code

```
try{
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:/Bookessais.xls"));
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem( input );
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        HSSFRow row;/* Initialisation*/
        HSSFCell cell = null;
        int theColIndexYouWant = 3;
        int cols = row.getLastCellNum();// ERROR LINE

        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowIndex++) 
        {
             row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
             if (row != null) {
                 double key = 0.0;
                 for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < cols; colIndex++) 
                 {
                     if (colIndex == theColIndexYouWant) 
                     {
                       int colIndex1 = colIndex - 3;
                       String key1;        

                       cell = row.getCell(colIndex);
                       if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC== cell.getCellType())

                          key = cell.getNumericCellValue();

                     System.out.println("\n");
                     System.out.println(" the key is---" +key);
                     System.out.println(" initial date is: "+ exDate);
                     if(key == exDate){ System.out.println(" IT IS A MATCH!");}
                     else  System.out.println(" NOT A MATCH");

                     cell = row.getCell(colIndex1);

                      key1 = cell.getStringCellValue();
                      if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING==cell.getCellType())
                      System.out.println(" the task is: " +key1+ " Line: "+rowIndex);        
                     }

              }

        }     

     }


    }
         catch ( IOException ex ) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
```

i tried to catch Null pointer exception but it did not work as well. Can i have some help please?
thanks

Comment: why did not you use `try catch` block?!

Comment: HSSFRow row;/* Initialisation*/ is declaration not initialization. your row is null at the point where you get the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize it by getting the first row of your sheet:

```
HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(sheet.getFirstRowNum());
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare your `row`variable but never initialise it. So when you call `row.getLastCellNum();`, it is still `null`. And you cannot call a method on an object that is `null`. It will throw the error you receive!

to solve the problem, attribute a value to your variable as defined by what purpose it is to serve. By the excerpt you give I could only guess at what it should be!

*Edit:* as you only use `cols` in the termination condition of your nested for loop, move the declaration of the variable just before the loop. It is also a good practice to use the minimum scope for variables.

```
double key = 0.0;
int cols = row.getLastCellNum();
for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < cols; colIndex++)
// and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you  for all the replies .Nikis suggestion did the trick! we will see how it runs

Comment: While he is right, I believe the instantiation is not necessary. You should not initialise variables for the sake of initialising them but because it is correct to do so. Here, the variable is not needed in the scope it is declared. Only initialising it in the loop will likely (at least I think so) enable automatic code optimisation to rescope the variable as needed. Always use the smallest scope necessary!

Answer (score 0):

Try placing this line `int cols = row.getLastCellNum();` after `row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);` . You need to get a row from a defined sheet to be able to do any operation with the row.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put "`int cols = row.getLastCellNum();`" after initialization into the loop like

```
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowIndex++) 
        {
             row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
             cols = row.getLastCellNum();
             ....
}
```